# error while fetch data to uipickerview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, uipickerview

i want to fetch the records from the core data entity and want other records to be entered against that one.

I have two core data entities Category and Product

i have made their relationship as well.

i have done with the category part.

now i want to add Products against the selected category.

for that i am using a `UIPICKERVIEW` to show the category and the name is then stored against it in product.

Here is the NSObject subclass Product.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Category;

@interface Product : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * is_active;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descript;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Category *category;

@end
```

and .m file

```
#import "Product.h"
#import "Category.h"


@implementation Product

@dynamic name;
@dynamic is_active;
@dynamic descript;
@dynamic category;

@end
```

What i am trying to do where to show the picker.

IMSAddProductViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IMSAddProductViewController : UIViewController < UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryPicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtEnterName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtEnterDescription;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *txtIsActive;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *arr;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;

- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender;
```

@end

i Don't know what should be edited here in this code to show the picker records..

IMSAddProductViewController.m

```
#import "IMSAddProductViewController.h"
#import "IMSAppDelegate.h"
#import "Product.h"
#import "Category.h"

@interface IMSAddProductViewController ()
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
}
@end

@implementation IMSAddProductViewController
@synthesize arr;
@synthesize txtIsActive;
@synthesize categoryArray;
@synthesize txtEnterName;
@synthesize txtEnterDescription;


   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        IMSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        NSEntityDescription *category = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Category"];
        request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

        request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[category propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"arr"]];


        NSError *error;
        NSMutableArray *results = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
        if (results == nil) {
            //error handle here
        }
        [self setArr:results];
          NSLog (@"name: %@",categoryArray);
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
    (UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
       // return _countryNames.count;
        return arr.count;
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
                 titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        //return _countryNames[row];
        return arr[row];
    }


    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
          inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        categoryArray = [self.arr objectAtIndex:row];
    }
```

when i go to this it view it throws exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
```

'*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object
    from objects[0]'

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in `if (results == nil) {//error handle here}` to see if it's ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html)., you need to set the `resultType` of the `NSFetchRequest` to `NSDictionaryResultType`.
Include this in `viewDidLoad` after `request.propertiesToFetch`:

```
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;   
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

Also, replace

```
[self setArr:results];
```

with

```
NSArray* results2 = [resultsvalueForKeyPath:@"arra"];
[self setArr:results2];
```

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryPicker;
     Puneet you see i didn't use this above line anywhere where to use this because putting some code to this will show results i guess

Comment: First you must have the fetched values. The code above will fetch it for you. Then you must set UIPickerViewDelegate to self. Then the delegates which you have set will start doing their work. Use debugging to ensure you are getting objects and values and delegate methods are getting called.

Comment: request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[category propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"name"]];
     Puneet i have edited this line in view did load 
also edited this    [self setArr:results];
      NSLog (@"name: %@",arr);

Comment: now i am getting the name of the categories can you please tell me that now how i will pass them to the uipickerview

Comment: Have you set UIPickerView's delegate property to your view controller in your nib? If you have not, you can do it programmatically. In viewDidLoad method write somewhere.. self.categoryPicker.delegate = self; Then the delegate methods will get called, which you have already set. The only thing I do not like is the way you are referring to your arr object. Replace arr with self.arr in the delegate methods.

Comment: i am not using nib or xib i have empty app with storyboard.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Do it programmatically. This will make your deleagates getting called. Also, dont forget to change arr to self.arr.

Comment: i have changed arr to self.arr  per ye konsa error ha ab ye pata nahi
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x812f0e0'

Comment: -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
          inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        categoryArray = [self.arr objectAtIndex:row];
    }
have a look at this line as well category array is a NSMutableArray while arr is NSArray.

Comment: Have you done this...NSArray* results2 = [resultsvalueForKeyPath:@"name"];
[self setArr:results2];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38192/discussion-between-ios-learner-and-puneet)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054493/error-while-fetch-data-to-uipickerview

Comment: Please have a look to this above link as well

Comment: yes puneet i have fetched the name form the column of one entity what should be stored from the picker in the 2nd entity where the relation exist you can see it in that question as well i have posted a lil bit more over there

Comment: i don't know some ppl have this kind of insect.... any way puneet please help me to sort it out.